# Remove unused variable declarations automatically - Android Studio/Inteiij

Tags: android-studio

Is there a way to remove all unused field declarations automatically in Android Studio/Intellij ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669093/remove-unused-variable-declarations-automatically-android-studio-inteiij

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Select `Analyze > Run Inspection by Name...`, type `unused declaration` and confirm with <kbd>Enter</kbd>. When the search is finished, select `Unused declaration` from the result tab, right click and select `Safe delete`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As simple as that, just press ctrl+alt+shift+I and type unused declaration.
You can also use this in removing other unused resouces, for example press ctrl+alt+shift+I and type unused resources. When the search is finished, select Unused declaration from the result tab, right click and select Safe delete