# How to skip unsafe usages when trying to delete unused declarations in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

I am aware that Androd Studio can find unused declarations in your project. You just run the "Unused declarations" inspection, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30669093/remove-unused-variable-declarations-automatically-android-studio-inteiij).

However, sometimes when you try to delete multiple unused declarations all together, you get warnings such as these:

```
constructor whatever() has 1 usage that is not safe to delete.
field whatever has N usages that are not safe to delete.
method whatever() implements whatever
```

I understand that I need to look at those warnings individually to make sure I am deleting without breaking code.

However, if I try to delete many unused declarations, even if one of them has a single unsafe usage, Android Studio won't delete anything at all. For example, suppose Android Studio found 50 unused declarations in my project. I multiselect all of them (using the Shift Key) and then click the "Safe Delete" button. If one of those 50 unused declarations has at least one unsafe usage, the other 49 won't be deleted, even if they were ready to be deleted without problem.

What I would like to know is if Android Studio allows to delete multiple unused declarations, and if it finds one unsafe usage, skip that unused declaration BUT keep going with the other ones.

In my project I have tons of unused declarations, but I can't delete many of them because there are some that trigger the warnings above. But most of them don't trigger any warning: I can browse my code files and find greyed out methods and I can safe delete them individually.

I have the latest version of Android Studio, 4.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ has several bugs regarding unsafe usages.
What I normally do is, after running the unused declarations inspections, I group the results by packages. Then, I try to delete all the unused usages of a particular package. I go through every package, one by one. That way, I minimize the number of unsafe usages found and can resolve them there at the spot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that has already been reported to JetBrains.

You can track it here and upvote it.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247964